# how to set dynamic path for <local-path> of virtual directory mapping in weblogic.xml

Tags: java, server, weblogic, virtual-directory, virtual-file

Depends on my Environment the service name will gets change for weblogic, In order to use Virtual directory mapping i'll have to pass this path exmpl /usr1/SIR1234 which is hard coded and differ from environment to environment.

So i need to pass dynamic values for this path

```
<virtual-directory-mapping>
 <local-path>/usr1/SIR123456/</local-path>
 <url-pattern>repo/*</url-pattern>
</virtual-directory-mapping>
```

how to pass dynamic values to  if environment gets changes it should not be changed like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deployment descriptors such as weblogic.xml files do not support dynamic values. Instead, you can use a deployment plan to externalize these different values for each environment where you will deploy your application. Read this [documentation](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/09-DeployPlan--4464/deployplan.htm) for details about deployment plans.